# Bar Mitzvah Meal Before Becoming 13

Tags: halacha, meal-seudah, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Mishne Berura, I believe,  writes that a Bar Mitzvah seudah (meal) is conferred the status of a seudas mitzvah if either it is held on the day of the boy's becoming 13 (i.e. his birthday) or, he delivers a dvar Torah.

If it is not practical to celebrate the Bar Mitzvah seudah on the boy's birthday, may it be held earlier -- before the boy becomes 13 -- **and have the status of a Seudas Bar Mitzva** as long as the boy delivers a dvar Torah, or must it be held after his birthday since one can't celebrate an event that has not yet occurred?

Obviously, the aliyah laTorah and all activities that require one to be actually a Bar Mitzvah and obligated in mitzvos will be held *after* the boy becomes 13.

Please provide sources to Poskim in your answer.

Comment: There is also the related question of celebrating an event before it actually takes place (e.g. birthday) connected to ayin hara (evil eye).

Comment: There are Mishnayot that discuss giving the Pidyon haBen money to a Cohen before the 30th day. Just saying.

Comment: Can you cite this mishna berura

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the source for a Bar Mitzva seuda?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28667/what-is-the-source-for-a-bar-mitzva-seuda)

Comment: @DoubleAA MB is 225 (2) **[6]**

Comment: As listed in an answer to [this M.Y. question][1], citing Magen Avaraham O.C. 225:4: [1]: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28667/what-is-the-source-for-a-bar-mitzva-seuda if the Bar Mitzvah boy gives a D'var Torah, it is a Se'udat Mitzvah even if not done on the day of the Bar Mitzvah.

Comment: @DanF The question is specifically whether it will  have the status of a Seudas Bar Mitzva. The status of a plain Seudas Mitzva was assumed in the question, citing the Mishne Berurah's citation of Magen Avraham.

Comment: @Yoni - Good point; thanks. My understanding of Bar Mitzvah - there is no requirement or "mitzvah" per se in making a se'udah for the Bar Mitzvah, thus, the occasion of Bar Mitzvah, itself does not create a mitzvah for the se'udah on its own. It is only because of a D'var Torah or Siyum done that creates a Se'udat mitzvah. In that sense, it is no different than other se'eudei mitzvah where a siyum is made. Perhaps, that's incorrect?